# How do I align some object to both axis in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

I want to lay out my view like the above and structure my code like this

```
return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.folder, size: 128,),
            Text("Folder - 1"),
          ],
        ),
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert)
        ),
      ],
    );
```

But what I've got is this...

[image]

It doesn't look nice like the above. How do I align like that? I'm new to Flutter please help

Answer (score 0):

You need two columns to achieve this.

Don't use IconButton because it contain default padding.

following code may help you more.

```
 Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            Icons.folder,
            size: 128,
          ),
          Text("Folder - 1"),
        ],
      ),
      Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          GestureDetector(child: Icon(Icons.more_vert)),
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Container(
  height: 28,
  child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert)),
),
```